# OpenIMS - Mobicents AS integration

Tags: restcomm, mobicents, ims

I am newbie to use Mobicents AS and would like to integrate mobicents AS with OpenIMScore. Could any one referred me link or guide me here

Below are my configuration details and running in VM:

```
10.0.0.9    hss.net1.test
10.0.0.10   pcscf.net1.test
10.0.0.11   icscf.net1.test
10.0.0.12   scscf.net1.test
```

I am able to make a Voice/Video call with in the OpenIMS.
Can any one guide me here please.

Regards,
-kranti

Answer (score 0):

After authentication, the S-CSCF should send a SAR to the HSS.  In the response, there should be a Cx-User-Data AVP which contains a XML document with the IMS data for the subscriber.  As a starting point, you could provision a single InitialFilterCriteria with no TriggerPoints, and a default ApplicationServer which will handle all SIP methods.

Here's a simple working example from my test bed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IMSSubscription>
  <PrivateID>ronmcleod@provider1.test</PrivateID>
  <ServiceProfile>
    <PublicIdentity>
      <BarringIndication>0</BarringIndication>
      <Identity>sip:ronmcleod@provider1.test</Identity>
    </PublicIdentity>
    <InitialFilterCriteria>
      <Priority>0</Priority>
      <ApplicationServer>
        <ServerName>sip:defaultapp@tas.core.ims1.test</ServerName>
        <DefaultHandling>0</DefaultHandling>
      </ApplicationServer>
    </InitialFilterCriteria>
  </ServiceProfile>
</IMSSubscription>
```

Comment: Could you provide any user guide/Weblink or step by step procedure to integrate with OpenIMS , please. It would helpful for me.